# LINQ custom function in .where

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

can I, and if I can, how, write LINQ statement like this:

```
public IQueryable<Advert> SearchSimilarAdverst(string query)
    {
        Levenshtein compute = new Levenshtein();
        return _db.Adverts.Where(a => a.IsActive  && 
              (compute.FindSimilarity(a.Name, query) <= 2));
    }
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've tired solution [Jeffery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212566/jeffery-khan) suggested and it worked but when I've tried this line of code I got EntityCommandExecutionException, does anybody know why ?

```
adverts.Where(a => a.WhoAmILookingForTags.Any
             (t => compute.FindSimilarity(t.Name,query) <= 2));
```

Tags and Adverts are connected with many to many relation, and WhoAmILookingForTags is list of tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF will not be able to translate `compute.FindSimilarity(a.Name, query)` to SQL, so you're going to have to take the performance hit and do the following.

```
public IEnumerable<Advert> SearchSimilarAdverst(string query)
{
    Levenshtein compute = new Levenshtein();
    var adverts = _db.Adverts.Where(a => a.IsActive).ToList();
    return adverts.Where(a => compute.FindSimilarity(a.Name, query) <= 2));
}
```

*Note the return type of the method also needed to be changed to reflect the return type*

As commented below, the query should be forced to run before filtering using `FindSimilarity` because of delayed execution.  `query.ToList()` is one of many options.

Comment: -1. `Where` employs deferred execution, and so this will still try to hit the database with that method and fail.

Comment: @IronMan84  realized that 2 seconds after I submitted.  Corrected, thanks.

Comment: `.ToArray` would be a better choice than `.ToList`.

Comment: @Jeffery and if I don't want to take performance hit, how would I do it then ?

Comment: That greatly depends on what the filtering method does.  If it is something that can be translated into the `Where` clause of your query, then you should place it there.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no - because EF needs to be able to convert your Linq predicate into T-SQL (or whatever dialect of SQL your RDBMS uses). Only a subset of .NET BCL functions are supported (such as `String.Contains` and custom user code is right-out).

For complicated predicates I recommend writing your own SQL by hand - you'll also get considerably better performance, EF can be slow at generating SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm wrong on this, but I do not believe that you would be allowed to that in a Linq-to-Entities query. In those kinds of LINQ queries it has to translate everything in the `Where` function into a SQL statement to be run on the underlying database. Since your method is not something that is on the SQL side of things, it will cause an exception when you try this.

For a regular LINQ query (i.e. after everything has already been put into memory), there should be no problem with accomplishing this.

You could also try it and see if it does or does not work...