# "Cannot access non-static property", but making the field static or instantiating it brakes the code

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query and I think I am doing somthing with Lambdas. (don't really know what it's called, I am very new to this)

This is my code:

```
    private static readonly Func<customer, string>[] _searches;

    static Main()
    {
        _searches = new Func<customer, string>[]
        {
            (c) => customer.city,
            (c) => customer.state,
            (c) => customer.country
        };
    }

    protected virtual void SearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerContext context = new CustomerContext();

        var search = _searches[ComboBox1.SelectedValue];

        IQueryable<customer> customers = from x in context.customers
                                         where search(x).Contains(SearchBox.Text)
                                         select x;
        loadList(customers);
    }
```

Now my problem is that I get an error at `customer.city`, `customer.state` and so on.

The error is:

> An object reference is required for the for the non-static field, method or property 'customer.city' Cannot access non-static property 'city' in static context

I have tried making the field `static` but that breaks the code, when I try to instantiate the field it breaks aswel. Or atleast, when I change `customer.city` to `new customer().city` I thought that's called instantiating, but I am not 100% sure.

So, how do I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

```
 private void loadList(IQueryable<customer> customers)
        {
            ListView.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var customer in customers)
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(customer.customerNumber.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.customerName);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.contactFirstName);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.contactLastName);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.phone);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.addressLine1);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.addressLine2);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.city);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.state);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.postalCode);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.country);
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.salesRepEmployeeNumber.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(customer.creditLimit.ToString());

                ListView.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
            }
        }
```

Comment: customer is a *type name*, not an object reference as required to access a member like city.  Surely you meant to use c instead, the first argument of the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Func<customer, string>[] _searches;
```

means that you declare an array of functions that return a string and receive an instance variable of type *customer*

but when you write

```
 (c) => customer.city,
```

here you are not using the instance passed (c) but you access directly the class *customer* by its name and this works only for properties, methods or fields that are declared as *static*

Instead you just need to use the *customer* instance that has been passed to you at the *where search(x)*  where x is the instance of a customer extracted by your line *from x in context.customers* and you receive in the Func as the variable named *c*

```
 (c) => c.city,
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But I now get the following error: `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.` when I am loading in my listview. You can see the code for that in de question.

Comment: @Luuk The problem here comes from how Linq works. In short: in order to build efficient queries, Linq converts common functionality (like `.toLowercase()`) to an sql equivalent. However, when you use custom functions like you did, it won't know how to translate. More details: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5284912/314056

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417714/linq-custom-function-in-where

Comment: Okay, I have looked at those questions and tried something but I does not really work and I don't really get it. I am sorry, but can you please help me?

Comment: I suppose that the best action is to post a new question with the details of the error. It is now something different and I can't help you on that

Comment: Okay, Will do that. Thanks for your help anyway.